How could i create an interactive map (image) that scales with screen size
Bit of context, I am IT/Security support in a school environment and we have about 100 cameras. I currently have a campus map that has the camera views "overlayed" (think green cone shapes roughly showing the view of each camera.
Unfortunately, a lot of these cameras are in similar positions but are facing different ways, or we have 2 basketball courts but are in different locations so my colleagues often can't accurately describe the camera they want footage from.
I want to create an interactive map that my colleagues/executive team can click on the camera (green cone) and it tells them the camera's unique name/ID in the CCTV management software.
I have tried using an HTML image map but it doesn't scale with screen size so can't be easily used on tablets, desktops or mobile.
I have thought about trying to use MS power apps but I can only put rectangle buttons in, not conical shapes/polygons.
Bonus points if it could link to a form that says "you have chosen Camera A, what period of time would you like footage for?" and then sends me an email...
Ive tried very limited things and have no thoughts as to where I could go from here. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!
I have very limited coding experience but would be very willing to learn if I can be pointed in the right direction!



const allDots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");
const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

const handleDots = (e) => {
  popup.style.display = "block";
  text.textContent = e.target.dataset.text;
};

const handleButton = () => {
  popup.style.display = "none";
  text.textContent = "";
};

allDots.forEach((dot) => {
  dot.addEventListener("click", handleDots);
});

btn.addEventListener("click", handleButton);
.map {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.dot-1 {
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}

.dot-2 {
  top: 40%;
  left: 80%;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
    <div class="map">
      <img
        class="img"
        src="https://cs14.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2023/02/11/6/1676106946166691447.png"
        alt="map"
      />
      <div data-text="u choose dot1" class="dot dot-1"></div>
      <div data-text="u choose dot2" class="dot dot-2"></div>
      <div class="popup">
        <div class="text">empty</div>
        <button class="btn">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>



Link for codesandbox
link

To make the image adaptive, set the img width to 100%. Then it will take up the entire width of the container and will be adaptive.
Set position:relative for the container. This will help to positions dots relative on it.
Set position:absolute to all necessary dots. Position them from top and left. Use percentages when positioning. This will make them adaptive.
There are many different solutions for information output and sending. I will provide you with the simplest option in my opinion through the dataset, using this draft you can pick up the necessary data and further process them.
To implement popup, you can use the provided draft or refer to libraries based on js. (popup.js as example).


I really appreciate this answer, it's almost exactly what i want! would there be any way to change it from changing text at the bottom of the page to a pop up? I am really quite new to "coding" in any capacity except VBA :)

Yep, of course. I edited solution. Happy codding!
